# Javascript .replaceAll() is not a function type error

Tags: javascript, typeerror

The documentation page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

```js
let string = ":insertx: :insertx: :inserty: :inserty: :insertz: :insertz:";
let newstring = string.replaceAll(":insertx:", 'hello!');
```

When I run this, I receive `Uncaught TypeError: string.replaceAll is not a function`. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what a prototype is, but the function appears to be a string method that is available for use.

I'm using Chrome.

Comment: where exactly did you get the idea that `.replaceAll()` is a String method

Comment: the example code in the documentation link, and it being in the title on the docs

Comment: Have you tried the replace method?

Comment: it would probably work, but why doesn't replaceAll?

Comment: `replaceAll ` comes in a few months as a native V8 string method. for now, it's still not available.

Comment: Go ahead and Polyfill it

Comment: @Pointy https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

Comment: @Opcode it's apparently new (or new-ish)

Comment: I faced same issue by using replace and replaceAll with match string as string instead of regex in typescript later replaced with regex it started working.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`.replaceAll` will be available starting on Chrome 85. The current version is 83.

If you download Google Chrome Canary (which is on version 86), you'll be able to see that your code runs fine. Firefox is on version 78, and since `.replaceAll` has been available starting version 77, it works there too. It will work on current Safari as well. Microsoft Edge has it as unsupported.

You'll find supported browser versions at the bottom of the article in your question.

Answer (score 108):

Use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regular expression with the global [modifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags) for better browser support. (Check the [browser compatibility table on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#browser_compatibility) to see which version of each browser started supporting the `replaceAll` method.)

```js
let string = ":insertx: :insertx: :inserty: :inserty: :insertz: :insertz:";
let newstring = string.replace(/:insertx:/g, 'hello!');
console.log(newstring);
```

For a more generic solution, we can escape regular expression metacharacters and use the `RegExp` constructor. You could also add the function to `String.prototype` as a polyfill.

(It is necessary to escape the string to replace so that characters that have special meanings in regular expressions will be interpreted literally, e.g. `.` will refer only to actual dots rather than any character.)

```js
//Taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions
function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
}
function replaceAll(str, match, replacement){
   return str.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(match), 'g'), ()=>replacement);
}

console.log(replaceAll('a.b.c.d.e', '.', '__'));
console.log(replaceAll('a.b.c.d.e', '.', '$&'));
```

A specification-compliant shim can be found [here](https://github.com/es-shims/String.prototype.replaceAll).

Comment: why do you use a callback function (`() => replacement`) instead of a simple string (`replacement`)?

Comment: @Ooker To prevent certain regex metacharacters from being interpreted, e.g. `$&`. For instance, `'aaaa'.replace(/a/g, '$&'))` gives `'aaaa'` instead of the desired `'$&$&$&$&'` that results from `'aaaa'.replace(/a/g, () => '$&')`.

Comment: so the callback is the way to escape the string as well?

Comment: @Ooker Yes, you can consider it like escaping the replacement string.

Comment: can I do the same with the match? E.g. `str.replace(new RegExp( ()=>match, 'g'), ()=>replacement);`

Answer (score 34):

If you don't want to upgrade your Chrome nor use reg expressions (since they're less performant), you can also do this:

```js
let string = ":insertx: :insertx: :inserty: :inserty: :insertz: :insertz:";
let newstring = string.split(":insertx:").join('hello!');
```

And you can, of course, attach to the String prototype if you'd like it everywhere. But since the real replaceAll is more feature filled (supports regex), you'd be instead safer doing:

```
String.prototype.replaceAllTxt = function replaceAll(search, replace) { return this.split(search).join(replace); }
```

Comment: Awesome. This should have been the accepted answer as it offers also the solution and it covers up compatibility issues.

Answer (score 28):

You can define it yourself easily:

```
if(typeof String.prototype.replaceAll === "undefined") {
    String.prototype.replaceAll = function(match, replace) {
       return this.replace(new RegExp(match, 'g'), () => replace);
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
"fafa".replaceAll("a", "o");
>>> fofo
```

Comment: p ="fa.fa.fa".replaceAll(".", "o");
console.log(p); // oooooooo

Comment: It detects "." as a regex expression. Dot in regex selects all of the characters. To fix this issue, You should add a backslash: `"fa.fa.fa".replaceAll("\\.", "o")`

Comment: why do you use a callback function (`() => replace`) instead of a simple string (`replace`)?

Comment: Edited, Thanks @Ooker

Comment: [as explained by @Unmitigated above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62825358/javascript-replaceall-is-not-a-function-type-error/67750739?noredirect=1#comment136031661_62825372 ""), the callback helps escaped the string

Answer (score 10):

`str.replaceAll` function is added in ES2021 (ES12), that's why it is not defined in older versions of browsers, and nodejs.

Comment: why doesn't nodejs support this?

Comment: Because it's new.

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting the same type error issues with `replaceAll`. I resolved it with replace method with regular expression with global flag set.

```js
let unformattedDate = "06=07=2022";
const formattedString = unformattedDate.replace(/=/g, ':');
console.log(formattedString);
```

Answer (score 2):

Although a bit off-topic, but I stumbled here for my use case which is not listed so here is for someone like me. I needed to hide a word but if it **starts** with certain characters i.e. dev. And, there is wild-card character ***** that helped me do it.

```
'Fullstack developer'.replace(/dev.*/g, '') // => Fullstack
```

Note: Notice the dot.

Answer (score 1):

## If you decide to declare the `replaceAll()` method to the string prototype, don't forget to escape the string

```
function escapeRegex(string) {
  return string.replace(/[/\-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&");
}

String.prototype.replaceAll = function(match, replace) {
  const escapedMatch = escapeRegex(match) 
  return this.replace(new RegExp(escapedMatch, 'g'), () => replace);
}
```

The problem is, once you have done that, the method cannot accept regex input anymore. In this case it's best to just use the `replace()` method.

Answer (score 0):

As I am not that familiar with Regex, I wrote a simple workaround to gain the same results as before. In the example, I want to replace any whitespace by an "X"

```
while (myString.includes(' ')) 
{
 myString = myString.replace(' ', 'X')
}
```

So just iterate through your string as long as the substring you want to replace is found.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem on node.
updated node from v14.17.1 to v16.18.0 and it was working for me.