# Block a certain character in textArea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

Basically i have a text area where the user can't type '%', there's no need to show warnings/alerts, what's the most simple way to do it?

Any suggestion on how to handle this?
I don't know if i have to create a function to make this work...

```
<div class="col-md-12 label-base">

                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Justify</label>

                <textarea style="resize: none"  ng-disabled="negociacaoEspecCtrl.proposta.flagDesabilitaEdicaoProposta"
                 class="form-control observacoes" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" ng-model="negociacaoEspecCtrl.proposta.dadosCadastro.negociacaoEspecial.justificativaNegociacaoEspecial"> 
               </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: The simplest and most sensible way to do this would be to actually allow the user to type '%' and then escape the characters you don't want since you don't intend to warn them that the '%' key doesn't seem to be working when they type. You can use  encodeURI() or encodeURIComponent() https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp. Alternatively see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302746/ignoring-input-characters-on-key-down

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.replaceAll()`. Add an event listener to the textarea and replace every occurence of `%` with a blank string every time the user inputs into the textarea.

```js
var txtarea = document.getElementById("exampleFormControlTextarea1");
txtarea.addEventListener("input", function() {
  txtarea.value = txtarea.value.replaceAll("%", "");
})
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 label-base">

  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Justify</label>

  <textarea style="resize: none" ng-disabled="negociacaoEspecCtrl.proposta.flagDesabilitaEdicaoProposta" class="form-control observacoes" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" ng-model="negociacaoEspecCtrl.proposta.dadosCadastro.negociacaoEspecial.justificativaNegociacaoEspecial">
</textarea><br/>
Try entering '%' into the textarea above
</div>
```

This prevents user from **pasting**/entering the character `%`

For better browser support for `.replaceAll()`, check out this question: [Javascript .replaceAll() is not a function type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62825358/javascript-replaceall-is-not-a-function-type-error)

Here's an example which notifies the user when the user inputs `%`:

```js
var txtarea = document.getElementById("exampleFormControlTextarea1");
txtarea.addEventListener("input", function() {
  var b4 = txtarea.value;
  txtarea.value = txtarea.value.replaceAll("%", "");
  if(txtarea.value != b4){
    console.log("You tried to enter %");
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 label-base">

  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Justify</label>

  <textarea style="resize: none" ng-disabled="negociacaoEspecCtrl.proposta.flagDesabilitaEdicaoProposta" class="form-control observacoes" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" ng-model="negociacaoEspecCtrl.proposta.dadosCadastro.negociacaoEspecial.justificativaNegociacaoEspecial">
</textarea><br/>
Try entering '%' into the textarea above
</div>
```

Or you can intercept the keydown event, although this won't block pasting:

```js
var txtarea = document.getElementById("exampleFormControlTextarea1");
txtarea.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if(e.key == "%"){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 label-base">

  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Justify</label>

  <textarea style="resize: none" ng-disabled="negociacaoEspecCtrl.proposta.flagDesabilitaEdicaoProposta" class="form-control observacoes" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" ng-model="negociacaoEspecCtrl.proposta.dadosCadastro.negociacaoEspecial.justificativaNegociacaoEspecial">
</textarea><br/>
Try entering '%' into the textarea above
</div>
```

Comment: The js code, i would put it into a function? My html dont have <header> and <body> tags, only divs; so i didn't managed to use <script>

Comment: @PedroPastori You can't execute JS without the <script> tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use Event.preventDefault() for this.

This method cancels the event if it is cancelable, meaning that the default action that belongs to the event will not occur, hence in our case, it will cancel the char being added to to the text area in case it is '%' (37 in ASCII code)

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById("textArea");
textarea.onkeypress = function(e) {
    if (e.which === 37){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
};
```

```html
<textarea id="textArea" rows="3" placeholder="enter text without %">
</textarea>
```

Comment: You can still paste the character into the textarea.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry @Ran. I was editing my code and somehow I've edited yours. Really sorry

Comment: Thanks @spectric for reverting it back

Comment: i need to put the script into a function? I don't know why but i tried to put this into a <script> inside header and it didn't work :(

Comment: did you also add the html to the body?

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for an answer, this seemed to work perfectly for me

```js
function removeChars(obj,evt){
    if (!(/\w/gm).test(evt.data))
        obj.value = obj.value.replace(evt.data,"");
}
```

```html
<textarea oninput="removeChars(this,event)"></textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add event lister for input in `textarea` and when user input the `%` then remove the last character from the `textarea` value.

```js
const textArea = document.querySelector("textarea");
textArea.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    textArea.value = textArea.value.replaceAll("%", "");
});
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 label-base">

  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Justify</label>

  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: @Spectric In that case we need to use `regex`. Exactly same as your answer